# Nitrous.io security audits/certifications?

Tags: nitrousio

I know nitrous.io uses amazon infrastructure.
Amazon have all security certifications i can remember. The infrastructure is secure. Is a fact!

However nitrous.io is a platform on top of amazon.
What security certifications do nitrous.io have to convince my boss to use it to host sensitive data that no person at action.io could see/copy/delete,etc

Its not enough amazon certifications, nitrous.io could have flaws.

I read the text at 
http://help.nitrous.io/admin-security/
http://help.nitrous.io/admin-privacy/
But that is just plain text

Do nitrous.io have security certifications/audits?